# Converting aff image to vdi using xmount

Tags: 16.04

I have a .aff (Advance Forensic Format) image, how do I go about converting the image to .vdi using xmount in ubuntu? I need to open the image in Virtual Box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption:

- In your working directory there is file `disk.aff`
- In your working directory you created new directory `vdifiles`

Then

`xmount --in aff --out vdi disk.aff vdifiles`

should create two `files` in `vdifiles`:

```
$ ls vdifiles
disk.info  disk.vdi
```

for import in Virtualbox.

You may use them directly or copy/convert to another place. If you want to use them direct without writing to the original, use the `cache`option:

`xmount --cache disk.ovl --in aff --out vdi disk.aff vdifiles`

See [xmount manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xmount.1.html)